# cannot succesfully build after busybox change (added i2cdetect & i2ctransfer)

Tags: stm32, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

## Setup:

VirtualBox 7.0
Image Ubuntu 22.04.1

## Goal:

rebuild Linux image for STM32MP157 in yocto project according [Digi-Key Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srM6u8e4tyw&list=PLEBQazB0HUyTpoJoZecRK6PpDG31Y7RPB&index=5&t=1629s) after adding i2cdetect in busybox

## Issue:

I guess main reason

```
Exception: FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/bin/busybox.suid' -> '/home/vboxuser/Projects/yocto/build-mp1/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.36.1-r0/package/usr/lib/busybox/ptest/bin/i2cdetect'
```

Whole log:

```
vboxuser@Ubuntu:~/Projects/yocto/build-mp1$ bitbake custom-image

Loading cache: 100% |#######################################################| Time: 0:00:04

Loaded 4039 entries from dependency cache.

NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies



Build Configuration:

BB_VERSION           = "2.4.0"

BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"

NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"

TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"

MACHINE              = "stm32mp1"

DISTRO               = "poky"

DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.2.3"

TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"

TARGET_FPU           = "hard"

meta                 

meta-poky            

meta-yocto-bsp       = "mickledore:2f5d4fa3495bea5ed0a4232b14cdeba39f27b75e"

meta-oe              

meta-python          = "mickledore:b0ba472191c2b7709ef04ae9c5a23bea040518f9"

meta-st-stm32mp      = "mickledore:931b3f5be2c00f55d114c8f9122082a9d229b776"

meta-custom          = "<unknown>:<unknown>"



WARNING: /home/vboxuser/Projects/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_1.36.1.bb:do_compile is tainted from a forced run

Initialising tasks: 100% |##################################################| Time: 0:00:09

Sstate summary: Wanted 13 Local 0 Mirrors 0 Missed 13 Current 1449 (0% match, 99% complete)

NOTE: Executing Tasks

ERROR: busybox-1.36.1-r0 do_package: Error executing a python function in exec_func_python() autogenerated:



The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:

File: 'exec_func_python() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>

     0001:

 *** 0002:ptest_update_alternatives(d)

     0003:

File: '/home/vboxuser/Projects/yocto/poky/meta/classes-recipe/ptest.bbclass', lineno: 110, function: ptest_update_alternatives

     0106:        for alt_name, alt_link, alt_target, _ in alternatives:

     0107:            # Some alternatives are for man pages,

     0108:            # check if the alternative is in PATH

     0109:            if os.path.dirname(alt_link) in bin_paths:

 *** 0110:                os.symlink(alt_target, os.path.join(ptest_bindir, alt_name))

     0111:}

     0112:

     0113:do_configure_ptest_base[dirs] = "${B}"

     0114:do_compile_ptest_base[dirs] = "${B}"

Exception: FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/bin/busybox.suid' -> '/home/vboxuser/Projects/yocto/build-mp1/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.36.1-r0/package/usr/lib/busybox/ptest/bin/i2cdetect'



ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/vboxuser/Projects/yocto/build-mp1/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.36.1-r0/temp/log.do_package.54781

ERROR: Task (/home/vboxuser/Projects/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_1.36.1.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'

NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3782 tasks of which 3777 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.



Summary: 1 task failed:

  /home/vboxuser/Projects/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_1.36.1.bb:do_package
```

After `bitbake -c do_cleanall busybox` & `bitbake -c do_cleanall custom_image` i'm able to succesfully build image but without i2cdetect
module

Seems that adding i2ctransfer in lieu i2cdetect cause same issue

I noticed that somebody already encountered this  [issue](https://lists.openembedded.org/g/openembedded-core/message/177475?p=%2C%2C%2C20%2C0%2C0%2C0%3A%3ACreated%2C%2Cbusybox%3A+always+start+do_compile+with+orig+config+files%2C20%2C1%2C0%2C97097235) with `busybox-1.35.0-r0` in *dunfell* branch, but my `meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc` file already has this patch.

Comment: How exactly did you enable the i2c components? With a cfg fragment, or some other way? Also, by any chance, have you added the full version of `i2c-tools` also to your image?

Comment: @skandigraun thank you for helping me out again, I used `bitbake -c menuconfig busybox` like in digi key tutorial. I will try approach with `i2c-tools` and give feedback about result

Comment: @skandigraun After append `i2c-tools` i was able to use i2c modules(including i2cdetect) Thanks! Anyway, if anybody would come up with idea why method from Digikey doesn't work i will be greatful 

Comment: I didn't mean to install it, just wanted to know if you have it installed already - was curious if the full and the busybox versions clash with each other. But if it works for you, that's also not too bad.